# How to combine date_add with generated always to calculate the dates in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7ab2ec9752c49009f98cb01944e837d7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Days (
    id int primary key,
    date_fix VARCHAR(255),
    date_calculated VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE_ADD("date_fix", INTERVAL 1 DAY))
);

INSERT Days
(id, date_fix, date_calculated
)
VALUES 
("1", "2019-01-01", ""),
("2", "2019-01-06", ""),
("3", "2019-05-01", ""),
("4", "2019-08-15", ""),
("5", "2019-10-03", "");
```

In the above table I want to insert a column called `date_calculated` which calculates the date as following:

```
date_fix + 1 day
```

Therefore, I tried to combine `GENERATED ALWAYS` with `DATE_ADD("date_fix", INTERVAL 1 DAY)` but I could not make it work so far.

I assume the issue is related to the `INSERT` statement since I currently use only `""` for the column `date_calculated` but I do not have any clue how to replace this `""` in order to achieve that the column is calculated as described.

Do you have any idea how to get the desired table with the calculated column?

Comment: I just don't get why you would need to store such easily derived data

Comment: Have you considered using a trigger instead?

Comment: Note that dates are normally stored using a date data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with a couple of fixes:

```
CREATE TABLE Days (
    id int primary key,
    date_fix VARCHAR(255),
    date_calculated VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE_ADD(date_fix, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
);

INSERT Days (id, date_fix)
VALUES (1, '2019-01-01'),
       (2, '2019-01-06'),
       (3, '2019-05-01'),
       (4, '2019-08-15'),
       (5, '2019-10-03');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b038ceded4419c0345fef55a4585c4d) is a db<>fiddle.

Your major issue is that you are quite confused by quotes.  When writing SQL, it is pretty simple:

- Use SINGLE quotes for date and string constants.
- Never use quotes at all for numbers.
- Do not use DOUBLE quotes (unless you really understand why you are using them).  MySQL extends SQL so this is a synonym for single quotes.

The second issue is that there is no need to insert a value into a generated column.  The value is calculated when you query the column, not when you insert values.

Then the third issue is types.  Do not store dates as strings.  MySQL has a wonderful data type to store dates, called `date`.  It was invented for a reason and you should use it.

Answer (score 2):

You should add DATE before DATE_ADD in your query

```
CREATE TABLE Days (
   id int primary key,
   date_fix VARCHAR(255),
   date_calculated VARCHAR(255) 
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(DATE_ADD(date_fix, INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
);
```

Then you can insert your data

```
INSERT INTO Days (id, date_fix)
    VALUES ("1", "2019-01-01"),
           ("2", "2019-01-06"),
           ("3", "2019-05-01"),
           ("4", "2019-08-15"),
           ("5", "2019-10-03");
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209206/discussion-between-tushar-and-digvijay-s).

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking to create the columns is not the right approach and not recommended.

The right approach for this logic would be, create the table with Id & date_fix only and then using select statement generate your calculated results.
**Why to use this method?**
As, You will be creating a new column unnecessarily to store the information which you can get from select statement will not be scalable enough to work in a large enterprise environment. So always try to minimize the load.

Please find the below code:

```
CREATE TABLE Days (
    id int primary key,
    date_fix VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT Days
(id, date_fix
)
VALUES 
('1', '2019-01-01'),
('2', '2019-01-06'),
('3', '2019-05-01'),
('4', '2019-08-15'),
('5', '2019-10-03');

select id,date_fix, DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(date_fix as DATETIME)) from Days;
```

Comment: I think OP is just trying out different options and this is not an actual design.